# linking 2 conflicting versions of a libraries

Tags: linux, linker, symbols

A third party vendor is releasing a prebuilt security library to me and I do not have access to it`s code or makefiles. This library is compiled against specific versions of openssl & protobuf. Problem is, the app I work on, chromium, is also using modified versions of these 2 libraries (well, technically boringssl is not openssl; but they share symbols). They are being compiled with the chromium source and being linked in statically. When I add the security library to chromium, I end up with 2 conflicting versions of the libraries and objects that are compiled against different headers. This of course leads to runtime crashes and unpredictable results. Is there anything I can do to make sure that everything is linked properly and symbols do not clash?

Comment: I'd consider asking the security vendor to supply you with the library statically linked against openssl and protobuf, as well as building it so that only symbols from the API are exposed to consumers. Because otherwise it will be a complete pain in the ass.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there anything I can do to make sure that everything is linked properly and symbols do not clash?

Your only real choices are:

1. Use `dlopen(..., RTLD_LOCAL);` on the 3rd-party library
2. Ask the vendor to give you a version built against Chromium tree.
3. Stop using this 3rd party library altogether.
4. The solution proposed by Petesh -- link openssl and protobuf statically into the 3rd party library and hide their symbols -- looks like another possibility, but has licensing implications. It looks like both protobuf and openssl allow for binary redistribution, so this may actually work, but IANAL.